# How to hide NavigationController on TabBar based iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm building a TabBar based iPhone app. I'm using xcode 4 and I add Navigation Controller as one of the item. It allows me to disable the Navigation Bar on the startup. I basically uncheck the **Shows Navigation Bar**.

Navigation Bar does not show on the start up. But once I navigate to the detail view and come back Navigation Bar is showing again. Please help where can I disable the Navigation bar?

**Update**

Guys I'm using tabBar based app and for some reason it never get into the ViewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 2):

In your viewWillAppear method of the view controller set `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` Everytime your viewController calls viewWillAppear it will setNavigationBar to hidden

Comment: for some reason it never get in to viewWillAppear, once I get back from detail view! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, and it's not getting into the ViewDidLoad method!

Answer (score 0):

put below code in your app delegate class in didFinishLaunching method :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```